# Read Excel xml file into R

Tags: r, xml2

I am trying to use xml2 to read an Excel xml file, but am having a hard time because the file I have is so different from the structures used in the xml2 documentation for examples. I want to read one of the worksheets from the workbook and use as a dataframe.

This snippet includes the complete structure, but only has one cell filled in with a bunch of text, whereas what I want to read has 50,000 rows of data.

```html
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<?mso-application progid='Excel.Sheet'?>
<s:Workbook xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:s="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
  <s:Worksheet s:Name="DBCitation">
    <s:Table>
      <s:Row>
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String">The suggested citation for your download is below. See metadata folder and citationsyntax.xls for more explanation</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
      <s:Row>
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String" />
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
      <s:Row>
        <s:Cell>
          <s:Data s:Type="String">Acosta-Martinez, Veronica ; Balkcom, Kipling; Caesar-TonThat, Thecan; Franzluebbers, Alan; Gollany, Hero; Jabro, Jalal; Jin, Virginia; Johnson, Jane; Liebig, Mark; Phillips, Rebecca; Sainju, Upendra; Sistani, Karamat; Skinner, R; Smith, Douglas; Stevens, William; Stott, Diane; Varvel, Gary; Venterea, Rodney; Acosta-Martinez, Veronica; Archer, David; Barbour, Nancy; Bucholtz, Dennis; Dell , Curtis ; Dillard, Anthony; Gross, Jason; Johnson, Holly; Knapp, Steven; Polumsky, Robert; Simmons, Jason; Upchurch, Dan; Waldron, Sarah; Weyers, Sharon; Wood, Charles; Zobeck, Ted; 2017; Daily Weather; Weather Station; Greenhouse Gas Flux Measurement; Supporting Research Measurement; All Cell Comments; All locations; ; 1929-2015; Database ver. og=gn08222 Fort Collins, CO: USDA-ARS REAP Database. File downloaded 1/30/2017 12:08:20 PM. PID:d4fa2478b1b144f58333e8a433e838b9</s:Data>
        </s:Cell>
      </s:Row>
    </s:Table>
```

Comment: Why not use a package made for reading Excel files, such as `readXL`, `XLConnect`, etc.?

Comment: I thought those were just for .xls or .xlsx?

Comment: An `xlsx` is just zipped `xml` document. I bet you could zip your file and use those just fine. Though maybe I'm misunderstanding your file.

Comment: Seems one can store Excel files in both "native" Excel format and in XML format. And the above snippet is coming from XML format which does not appear readable with "normal" Excel format readers..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`gnumeric` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gnumeric)'s function `read.gnumeric.sheet`.

Otherwise,  with `xml2` you can do something like:

```
readExcelXML <- function(filename, sheet) {
  doc <- read_xml(filename)
  ns <- xml_ns(doc)
  rows <- xml_find_all(doc, paste0(".//s:Worksheet[@s:Name='", sheet, "']/s:Table/s:Row"), ns = ns)
  values <- lapply(rows, . %>% xml_find_all(".//s:Cell/s:Data", ns = ns) %>% xml_text %>% unlist)

  columnNames <- values[[1]]

  dat <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(values[-1], stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  names(dat) <- columnNames

  dat
}
```

To get correct column types from the XML you would need to add:

```
  # assign types from file (automatically),
  # NB: hard-coded 2nd row of the data to take types from
  types <- rows[[2]] %>% xml_find_all(".//s:Cell/s:Data") %>% xml_attrs %>% unlist %>% setNames(nm = names(dat))
  funcs <- c("Number" = as.numeric, "String" = as.character, "DateTime" = . %>% as.POSIXct(format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S."))

  for (iCol in names(dat)) {
    dat[[iCol]] <- funcs[[types[iCol]]](dat[[iCol]])
  }
```

to the function.